# Trying to convert my old custom arara rule

Tags: arara

I have a rule which worked with the old version of arara:

```
!config
# Open the every <filename>.<format> that can be opened
# The default for <filename> is the current file.
# The default for <format> is pdf. 
# Sample usage: 
# - if myfile.tex is the current file, all these open myfile.pdf
# % arara: showfile
# % arara: showfile {format: pdf}
# % arara: showfile {filename: myfile, format: pdf}
# and both these open myfile.log:
# % arara: showfile {format: log}
# % arara: showfile {filename: myfile, format: log}
#
identifier: showfile
name: showfile
commands: 
- <arara> @{ isWindows( "cmd /c start", "xdg-open" ) } "@{ getBasename(file) }.@{format}"
arguments:
- identifier: format
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.format}
  default: pdf
```

According to [New version of arara broke my custom rule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440172/new-version-of-arara-broke-my-custom-rule) I have changed it into:

```
!config
identifier: showfile
name: showfile
commands: 
- command: <arara> @{ isWindows( "cmd /c start", "xdg-open" ) } "@{ getBasename(file) }.@{format}"
arguments:
- identifier: format
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.format}
  default: pdf
```

But if I run

```
arara main.tex
```

on a simple `main.tex`:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: showfile
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Test 
\end{document}
```

I only get:

[image]

and the `main.pdf` is not shown.

The task remains appended, and if I close the command prompt windows, I get:

```
Processing 'main.tex' (size: 98 bytes, last modified: 12/15/2018
19:40:31), please wait.

(PDFLaTeX) PDFLaTeX engine .............................. SUCCESS
(showfile) Unnamed task ................................. SUCCESS

Total: 339.97 seconds
<<< Process finished (PID=9956). (Exit code 0)
================ READY ================
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you try this new rule?

```
!config
identifier: showfile
name: Display
commands: 
- name: Show file
  command: >
    @{
      prefix = isWindows( [ 'cmd', '/c', 'start' ], [ 'xdg-open' ] );
      view = getBasename(file) + '.' + format;
      return getCommand(prefix, view);
    }
arguments:
- identifier: format
  flag: >
    @{
        return parameters.format;
    }
  default: pdf
```

Let me break the elements into sections:

```
!config
identifier: showfile
name: Display
```

Nothing new here, it's just the header: `showfile` is the identifier to be used as directive in the source code, and `Display` is the name to be printed as the main task in the terminal. `:)`

Moving on.

```
commands: 
- name: Show file
```

Now, we have a list of subtasks associated with this rule. In our case, we just have one element in the list. Each element consists of a name and a proper command. `Show file` is the name of this *subtask* and it will be displayed right after `Display` (the task name) in the terminal.

```
  command: >
```

The `>` symbol denotes the *folded* style for scalars. I highly suggest taking a look at the `arara` manual for a complete description of what it is. In short, it is a way of having multiple lines in a field (there's actually way more to that, but let's keep concepts easy to grasp for the uninitiated).

```
    @{
```

I simply opened the orb tag (please refer to the manual for more details on this concept). The rule logic will be described inside this tag.

```
      prefix = isWindows( [ 'cmd', '/c', 'start' ], [ 'xdg-open' ] );
```

`prefix` is a variable that holds the result of the following evaluation: if `arara` is being executed under Windows, return a list of strings containing `cmd`, `/c` and `start`. Otherwise, return a list containing only `xdg-open`.

```
      view = getBasename(file) + '.' + format;
```

In a similar fashion, `view` is a variable that holds the basename of the `file` reference plus a literal `.` and the format, obtained from the rule argument of the same name.

```
      return getCommand(prefix, view);
```

We now return a command composed of the `prefix` variable (properly flattened during command construction, please refer to the manual for more details) and the `view` variable. Introduced in version 4.0, the `Command` type is a robust way of making the underlying system know what to do. It's way more reliable than raw strings (deprecated in this version and to be removed in later versions).

```
    }
```

Now the orb tag is properly closed. Please mind the spaces that compose the folded representation of the current scalar. Otherwise, the YAML parsing will fail.

```
arguments:
```

Now we have the list of rule arguments, as usual. In our case, we only have one element, defined as follows.

```
- identifier: format
```

The argument name, to be used in the directive in the source code.

```
  flag: >
    @{
        return parameters.format;
    }
```

Again, I decided to use the folded style for scalar representation. In this case, the original representation in the OP's question is fine, it's just my personal preference. `:)`

```
  default: pdf
```

Then we have here the default value if this particular argument is not explicitly specified in the directive.

That's it. `:)`

Comment: @CarLaTeX: done. `:)`

Comment: Beautiful work :)